# Issue populating edit forms in Sharepoint 2013

Tags: 2013, web-part, sharepoint-online, infopath

So I have a SharePoint list where on the edit page I have created multiple infopath form webparts, each audiences to a different group with a different view. The problem is that only the first form is populating, so some users click edit and receive a blank form. Is there a way to ensure that all versions of the form populate?

Sorry if this is an overly basic question, I'm a little new to SharePoint.
Thanks again!